# Help me understand this differential equation solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found a differential equation in an old paper, where the solution is a bit hard to understand.

Given this equation:

$$\frac{1}{2} r^2 \left(\frac{d \phi}{dr}\right)^2 + c^2 \left(r \frac{d\phi}{dr} + \phi\right) = 0$$

Multiplication with $\frac{8}{c^4}$ and substitution with $\xi := 2 \frac{\phi}{c^2}$ leads to:

$$r^2 \left(\frac{d \xi}{d r}\right)^2 + 4 \left(r \frac{d \xi}{dr} + \xi\right)$$

Then he says with the new argument $\ln r$ and $\xi' = \frac{d \xi}{d(\ln r)}$ (I interpreted this as $\frac{d \xi}{d(\ln r)} = \frac{d \xi}{dr} \frac{d r}{d(\ln r)} = \frac{d \xi}{dr} r$) follows:

$$\xi'^2 + 4(\xi' + \xi) = 0$$

And then he solves this quadratic equation to

$$\xi' = -2\left(1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \xi}\right)$$

**Now the part that where I am stuck.** He says transformation with $Q' = \left(1 - \sqrt{1 + \xi}\right)$ results in $$d(Q' e^{-Q'}) = -d \ln r,$$ or integrated $$r Q' e^{-Q'} = C$$

And then he starts resubstituting $Q = ...$ and so on. But what kind of "transformation" is this? Can you add some intermediate steps?

Comment: is in the first equation $0.5r^2(\frac{d\phi}{dr})^2+...$ instead of  $0.5r^2(\frac{d\phi}{dr})+...$?

Comment: moreover, I would introduce $y=ln r$, i.e. $r=e^y$ and write $\frac{d\xi}{dy}=\frac{d\xi}{dr}\frac{dr}{dy}=\frac{d\xi}{dr}r$ to arrive at the 3rd equation

Comment: Yes, it's $\left(\frac{d \phi}{dr}\right)^2$. I edited my question.

Comment: thanks! It seems $Q(r):=1-\sqrt{1+\xi(r)}$ to me. The derivative $\frac{dQ}{dr}=\frac{dQ}{d\xi}\frac{d\xi}{dr}$ should be used in the relation $\frac{d}{dr}(Qe^{-Q}\stackrel{!}{=}-\frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: You are also right with the second part. It's $\dots = \frac{d \xi}{dr} r$, not $\frac{d \xi}{dr} \frac{1}{r}$. I edited the question again :)

Comment: I do not fully understand the equation with the exponential $e^Q$; does the author claim that  $(\xi')^2+4(\xi'+\xi)=0$ is equivalent to $d(Qe^{-Q})=-dln r$?

Comment: Yes, he claims that $\xi' = -2\left(1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \xi}\right)$ can be transformed with $Q' = \left(1 - \sqrt{1 + \xi}\right)$ to $d(Q' e^{-Q'}) = -d \ln r$. Please note the difference between $Q'$ and $Q$. Maybe $Q' = \frac{dQ}{dr}$.

Comment: Or maybe $Q' = \frac{dQ}{d(\ln r)}$?

Comment: Good point! Try to work the equation with $e^{-Q'}$ using $Q'=\frac{dQ}{dr}=\frac{dQ}{d\xi}\frac{d\xi}{dy}\frac{dy}{dr}$, and $\frac{dy}{dr}=\frac{dln r}{dr}$. It sounds reasonable to me.